# Chef - handle resources changing the network interface

Tags: openvpn, linux-networking, chef

I'm using chef to deploy an openvpn application in bridging mode to an ubuntu node.
In my recipe i'm using a bash resource to create the bridge necessary for the vpn to work. Unfortunately the bridge changes the ip-address of the node and chef therefore fails to finish (machine becomes unavailable on the previous ip).

How would you treat issues like this?